# prove $ (A^C \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (C \cup A) = (A^C \cup B) \cap (C \cup A) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove using the counting laws for quantities:

showing left side is equal to right side

1. $[(A^C ∩ (B∪C)) ∪ (B∩ (B∪C)) ] ∩ (C∪A) = $
2. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ (A^C ∩ C) ∪ (B∩B) ∪ (B∩C) ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
3. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ (A^C ∩ C) ∪ B ∪ (B∩C) ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
4. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ (A^C ∩ C) ∪ B] ∩ (C∪A) =$
5. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ (B ∪ A^C) ∩ (B∪C) ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
6. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ (A^C ∪ B) ∩ (B∪C) ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
7. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ A^C) ∪ B ∩ (B∪C) ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
8. $[(A^C ∩ B) ∪ A^C) ∪ B ] ∩ (C∪A) =$
9. $ (A^C ∪ B) ∩ (C∪A) $

is this correct? I'm unsure if line 4 to line 5 is right

Comment: Please lable your lines. Hard to see which lines are 3,4,etc. and good if users here want to refer to these or other lines.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you for your comment. Added the labels!

Comment: $4$ to $5$ is just distributive law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step between line 4 and 5 is correct.

If $x\in (A^C\cap C)\cup B,$ then $x\in B$ or $X\in A^C\cap C.$ If $x\in B$ then, obviously $x\in (A^C\cup B)\cap (C\cup B)$. If $x\in A^C\cap C$, then $X\in A^C\subset A^C\cup B$ and $x\in C\subset C\cup B$, so $x\in (A^C\cup B)\cap (C\cup B)$. Therefore $(A^C\cap C)\cup B\subset (A^C\cup B)\cap (C\cup B)$.

On the other hand, if $x\in (A^C\cup B)\cap (C\cup B)$, then $x\in A^C\cup B$, and $x\in C\cup B$. If $x\in B,$ then trivially $x\in (A^C\cap C)\cup B$. If $x\not\in B$, then $x\in A^C$ and $x\in C$, so $x\in A^C\cap C.$ This proves that $(A^C\cap C)\cup B=(A^C\cup B)\cap (C\cup B). $

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you for showing me this. I really need to work on my proofs!